# unable to use dateadd in sql along with update and where.

Tags: mysql, where-clause, dateadd

I am supposed to update the travel_date in the table schedule by adding 5 days for the travellers whose  source='chennai' and destination='bangalore'.
I wrote the following code to do so:

```
update schedule 
set travel_date=DATEADD(day,5,travel_date) from schedule where source='Chennai' AND destination='bangalore' ;
```

But I got an error :
"sql command not properly ended".
I am new to sql , is there a way to increment the **travel_date** member of **schedule** table by 5 days ?

Comment: Remove `from schedule`, and it should work. Your SQL should be: `update schedule set travel_date=DATEADD(day,5,travel_date) where source='Chennai' AND destination='bangalore' ;`

Answer (score 0):

You had used incorrect form for .[**UPDATE QUERY**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

```
update schedule 
set travel_date=DATEADD(day,5,travel_date) where source='Chennai' AND destination='bangalore' ;
```

Try above query.

Comment: I removed "from schedule" and got the following error:                           
  ORA-00904:"DATEADD":invalid identifier.

Comment: @VidyanshuDas R u using MySQL??

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
update schedule 
    set travel_date = travel_date + interval 5 day
    where source = 'Chennai' and destination = 'bangalore' ;
```

Your query is using SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @VidyanshuDas . . . Do you know what database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This command will work perfectly fine:

```
update SCHEDULE
set TRAVEL_DATE=TRAVEL_DATE+5 
where source='Chennai' 
  and destination='Bangalore';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE schedule 
SET travel_date=travel_date+5 
WHERE source='Chennai' 
  AND destination='Bangalore';
```

This is working.

Answer (score -1):

This actually worked for me.

I'm using MySQL:

Try this.

```
update Schedule
set travel_date = travel_date + 5 where SOURCE = 'Chennai' AND DESTINATION = 'Bangalore';
```